# Regex replace O with zero (Jquery input mask)

Tags: jquery, regex, masking

I'm using the excellent Igor Escobar Jquery mask plugin.  ( https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ )

On my input field, I want it so that if a user types in the letter O or o (capital or lower case "o") it gets replaced by a zero (0).

Using the documentation, I've got as far as being able to amend the regex by using translation:
`$('#myfield').mask('ooo-ooo', {'translation': {'o': {pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/}}});`

This regex pattern allows any alphanumeric character, which is great.  However, I need to amend this regex so that "O"s and "o"s get converted to 0 (a zero).

Is this possible solely by using regex (which I'm not very familiar with), or is there a better function of Jquery mask that I missed in the documentation to be able to do this?

It's basically replacing two specific characters with a different one, if typed.
Many thanks.

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to freedomn-m pointing me in the direction of the callback functionality, I got this working with a bit of ropey javascript:

```
var options =  {

  // Replace Os with Zeros
  onKeyPress: function(cep, options){
    var lastChar = cep[cep.length -1];
    if (lastChar=="o" || lastChar=="O") { 
        var newreplace = cep.substring(0, cep.length - 1);
        $('#myfield').val(newreplace + '0'); 
    }
  }
};

$('#myfield').mask('AAA-AAA', options);
```

Comment: Quick look at the docs for that plugin and it looks like the `translation` is simply a method to keep the mask clean - as in your example translating the *mask* `o` to your pattern.  It's not for translating inputs.  You can probably achieve this using the `callback`.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, you're right but I thought a custom regex could be used instead.
I'll have a closer look through the callback section.